# How to move an object from point of collision to end of the object | Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I am new in Unity and i am having some trouble in figuring out an issue.
I have a sprite which is just a plain square with boxCollider2d on it. A ball is suppose to collide on it, and i want that ball to travel smoothly from point of collision to the end of the square sprite. I have written some code but it doesnt seem to be working. The below script is on square sprite on which ball is falling.

```
public class HandleRollerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
 private float desiredDuration = 1f;
 private float elapsedTime = 0f;
 private Vector3 endPosition;
 private Vector3 startPosition;
 private Rigidbody2D eggRigidBody;
 private BoxCollider2D boxCollider2D;
 private float rollerLegth;

 private void Start()
{
    boxCollider2D = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
    rollerLegth = boxCollider2D.bounds.size.x;
}

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Egg"))
    {
        eggRigidBody = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        if (eggRigidBody != null)
        {
            startPosition = eggRigidBody.transform.position;
            Vector2 contactPoint = GetPointOfContact(collision);
            float ToMove = Mathf.Abs(rollerLegth - Mathf.Abs(contactPoint.x));

            endPosition = new Vector3(startPosition.x + ToMove, eggRigidBody.transform.position.y, 0);
            StartCoroutine(MoveEgg());
        }
    }
}

private IEnumerator MoveEgg()
{
    while (elapsedTime < desiredDuration)
    {
        eggRigidBody.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPosition, endPosition, (elapsedTime / desiredDuration));
        elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
        yield return null;
    }
    yield return null;
}
Vector2 GetPointOfContact(Collision2D collision)
{
    ContactPoint2D contactPoint = collision.contacts[0];
    Vector2 contactPosition = contactPoint.point;
    return contactPosition;
 }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `it doesnt seem to be working`? Is nothing happening on collision, etc? Might help to show your setup on the inspector menu. Eitherway, one potential issue might be that `OnCollisionEnter2D` is actually getting called more than once when the object collides, which causes your code to create more `MoveEgg` coroutines that makes some unintended effects.

Comment: what is `the end of the square sprite`? Do you mean you collide with a sprite -> you want to move smooth to the point where this entering ray direction hits the opposite edge of the sprite?

Comment: @WQYeo, let me explain. Actually the ball is travelling the same distance every time .Wether it collide in left corner, middle or right corner, it always travels the same distance to its right after colliding from the square. I am also adding link below.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/gIMAC0N

Comment: @derHugo, Yes, when ball collides with square, i want ball to move smoothly to the end of sprite and then fall under gravity.

Comment: @derHugo, I have added link too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is that in

```
float ToMove = Mathf.Abs(rollerLegth - Mathf.Abs(contactPoint.x));
```

you are using an absolute world space position `contactPoint.x` and subtract it from a plain size value.

Instead I would probably rather compare both bounds and do something like e.g.

```
var eggRigidBody = collision.rigidbody;

if(!eggRigidBody) return;

var startPosition = (Vector2)eggRigidBody.position;
var endPosition = startPosition;

// basically takes the right edge of this collider and adds the distance between the balls left edge and pivot position
endPosition.x = boxCollider2D.bounds.max.x + (startPosition.x - collision.collider.bounds.min.x);

// you might even need to add some additional buffer so the ball isn't stuck on the right edge
//endPosition.x += 0.1f;

StartCoroutine(MoveEgg(eggRigidBody, startPosition, endPosition, (endPosition.x - startPosition.x) / rollerLegth * desiredDuration);
```

and then accordingly pass those as parameters

```
private IEnumerator MoveEgg(Rigidbody2D rb, Vector2 startPosition, Vector2 endPosition, float duration)
{
    for(var elapsedTime = 0f; elapsedTime < duration; elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;)
    {
        rb.MovePosition(Vector2.Lerp(startPosition, endPosition, elapsedTime / duration));
        yield return null;
    }
    
    rb.MovePosition(endPosition);
}
```

Comment: thanks alot. That indeed was the issue.